# Manipulating the axis of a 2D graphic

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, 3d, perspective

I have made a flat 2D design in Illustrator that I want to change the viewer's perspective on. So where it is currently being viewed head-on or top-down, I'd like to skew the projected viewing angle to something less than 90 degrees (and off to a side while I'm at it).

Is this possible in Illustrator or do I need to use a 3D tool (and presumably, convert the logo to a 3D model)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really all depends upon the art.

You could use `Effect > 3D > Extrude & Bevel`
Or `Effect > 3D> Rotate`

You could use Illustrator's Perspective Grid to snap object to a perspective plane.

You could use the Free Transform Tool, click a corner then hold down <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> (Mac) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> (Win) then drag. Note; You MUST click and hold a handle, THEN hold down the modifier keys.